# render to floating point texture under iOS

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

The iPad now supports the `OES_texture_half_float`
extension.  Unfortunately I'm having trouble binding a floating-point texture to a framebuffer object.  Here's my attempt:

```
GLuint textureHandle;
glGenTextures(1, &textureHandle);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, 256, 256, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
assert(GL_NO_ERROR == glGetError()); // this passes

GLuint fboHandle;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboHandle);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboHandle);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle, 0);
assert(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE == glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)); // this asserts
```

This works fine when replacing `GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES` with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

Is this a limitation with iOS or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Are you checking GL errors? If not, do it, it might shed some light about the problem. Also, what does glCheckFramebufferStatus return?

Comment: glGetError returns GL_NO_ERROR at the end of this snippet.  glCheckFramebufferStatus returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT.

Comment: prideout, I've got the same error. Looks like there is no support of rendering to float texture on iOS devices yet. Since, OpenGL ES 2.0 specs mark this feature as not mandatory. Did you make any more research on that? Can confirm such limitation?

Comment: Yes, this appears to be a driver limitation.  I filed a bug against Apple. (8524103)  I hope they add support for this as it would enable a variety of effects.  For example: http://prideout.net/blog/?p=51

Comment: Did you manage to get it working in the end? Perhaps with later version of iOS?

Comment: More recent versions of iOS support EXT_color_buffer_half_float, which is required for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted a similar question on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621095/how-to-use-gl-half-float-oes-typed-textures-in-ios).

It seems that the [OES_texture_float extension](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt) is currently only supported on iPhone 4S and iPad 2, even though it's not explicitly mentioned in [Apple's guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH106-SW1).

Thanks to kal21 for [pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440543/how-to-use-float-textures-in-opengl-es-2-0-on-ios).