# iOS (iPhone) High Precision Texture Output

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to create a histogram of luminosity values from a large image (on the order of 2048 x 2048) to do so, I'm following [this method](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=histogram%20on%20gpu&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http://developer.amd.com/gpu_assets/GPUHistogramGeneration_I3D07.pdf&ei=n17UTufaG6PliALLmtDGDg&usg=AFQjCNHeBuMxtd63_67be-LK-qNh82Ai8A&sig2=skgZ6KvTih6Agn1Rr-isow) for calculating the histogram on the GPU.

Essentially, it boils down to creating a point for every pixel and texture sampling through the vertex shader at that point, then outputting a value of 1 / (number pixels) to a 1-dimensional texture (256 x 1). If you set the blend mode to glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE) this will mean your 1-dimensional texture will eventually accumulate the effective histogram.

However, in my experience the output texture doesn't have enough precision to increment by 1/number of pixels when the # of pixels is something reasonable.

Is there a way of increasing the precision of the texture on the *iPhone* to something that will accommodate increases of this precision?

Comment: I was looking at this very same problem! Could you tell me how you ended up summing the local histograms with a higher precision output?  I couldn't quite understand how the "gather" step in the paper worked. If you could briefly walk me through that render step, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the OpenGL ES on iOS doesn't support rendering to a texture of precision higher than one byte per color channel. See [render to floating point texture under iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850569/render-to-floating-point-texture-under-ios). You'll want to increment each bin by 1, which means your shader would output 1/256.

To prevent saturation, it seems you could use the technique described in Section 2.2 ("Precision Considerations for Bin Content Accumulation") of the paper you referenced. That is to distribute pixels among local histograms and then do a gather at the end.

Comment: Thanks Taylor! I was looking at this very same problem - what exactly do you mean by "do a gather at the end"? How would the second render pass for summing the local histograms be able to use a higher precision output? (Assuming we still want 256 bins in the final/merged histogram).

Comment: No problem! The gather phase wouldn't sum using blending, but rather would sum with floating point precision within a fragment shader. So if you rendered to several local histograms, that gather shader would sample from each of them to produce the final histogram. Floating point values could be packed to into RGBA colors to avoid precision problems in the output, since alpha blending isn't used.