# How to use Float textures in OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In my iOS OpenGL ES 2.0 program I have to store float values in the textures. Could you please 
let me know how to do this. I am aware that there is an extension for that purpose but not sure how to use that extension.

Comment: I posted a [similar but more specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621095/how-to-use-gl-half-float-oes-typed-textures-in-ios). As you can see I managed to use float textures... sort of. Maybe that helps you getting further. If you find out how to solve my problem, please let me know!

Comment: @FrankSchlegel I heard from people that float textures are only supported on iPhone 4S and iPad2.

Comment: @kal21 Do you remember who told you that and why that would be?

Comment: @twerdster I believe because of the hardware issue. The floats are not supported on older hardware. I got that info from http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org forums.