# How to use GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES typed textures in iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, floating-point, textures

I'm trying to create a float texture to store intermediate results of my rendering pipeline created by a fragment shader. I need the values of the fragments to be *signed floats*.

I understand that there is the [OES_texture_float](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt) extension which should be supported by all new iOS devices (i.e. beginning from iPhone 3GS/iPod Touch 3/iPad according to the [Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH106-SW1)).

However, when I create such a texture using

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, NULL);
```

start my app and inspect it in Instruments, it tells me:

> glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, NULL) : (invalid enum=0x8d61): Invalid enum for argument 'type'

The curious thing is that it's nevertheless working on my iPhone 4S, but not on a iPhone 4 (which should be supported as well). The error message appears for both devices, though. But on the iPhone 4 OpenGL can't build a valid framebuffer object using this texture as a rendering target. On the 4S that works perfectly well.

Do you have any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a year I faced the problem again. I did some research and finally found the solution:

On almost all iOS devices it is possible to create and use float and half-float-typed textures. In fact all devices that support the `OES_texture_float` extension (or `OES_texture_half_float`, respectively) allow the creation of float-typed textures.

**However**, if you are trying to render *into* a float-typed texture using a Framebuffer Object, the device needs to support the `EXT_color_buffer_half_float` extension as well. As the name suggests this extension allows to bind half-float-typed textures to the render target of an FBO.

Now it turns out that this extension is only supported on devices that have a PowerVR SGX 543 or 554 graphics card, which are basically all devices released after (and including) the iPhone 4S. You can refere to Apple's [OpenGL ES Hardware Platform Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/OpenGLES/Conceptual/OpenGLESHardwarePlatformGuide_iOS/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012935-CH106-SW1) for a list of devices and their capabilities.

### Summary:

If you want to render to a float-typed texture, you need to check if your device supports the `EXT_color_buffer_half_float` extension and you need to create your texture with

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, NULL);
```

If your device does not support half-float color buffers, you can only bind unsigned-byte-typed textures to your FBO:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

(Note that the format and internal format of the texture (`GL_RGBA` in this case) depends on the attachment point of the FBO.)

Comment: Hey, Are you able to render into a single-channel floating point texture?

The code would look something like this:

'glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED_EXT, width, height, 0, GL_RED_EXT, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, NULL);'

I am not able to get the output. It says FBO incomplete.

Comment: If the `EXT_texture_rg` extension is supported by your device (in addition to `EXT_color_buffer_half_float`) you should be able to bind single-channel float textures to an FBO. For me it works with 2-channel floats (`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RG_EXT, width, height, 0, GL_RG_EXT, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, NULL)`) and single-channel unsigned byte textures.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I got the half float working. Like you said, 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED_EXT, width, height, 0, GL_RED_EXT, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, NULL) . 

And this works on all devices from iPhone 4s onwards. Now, I am stuck with using float textures.  

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED_EXT, width, height, 0, GL_RED_EXT, GL_FLOAT, NULL)

But this is not working. I am getting framebuffer incomplete.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid you are doing nothing wrong, `GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES` is only supported on the iPhone4S and iPad2, despite there being no documentation to this effect. Float textures are a massive performance killer, even a basic variance shadow mapping implementation is completely unusable on an iPhone4S.

Comment: That's a pity, but I guess you are right. Btw. even on the iPhone 4S / iPad 2 I get the OpenGL error mentioned above. But it works, though... For me, the performance (speed-wise) is the same as for byte-typed textures. It's only the memory consumption that is twice as high.

Comment: For the record: the new iPad (3rd generation) can handle float-typed textures as well.