# How to create texture using GL_FLOAT in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures

When one calls:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rawData);
```

it's easy to know how to format the data: pass in an array of bytes, in the range 0-255, where 0 is lowest and 255 is brightest for each color component.

When you do the same with GL_FLOAT, you pass in an array of floats. My question is, what is the range of each color component value? 0 to 1.0? 0 to the maximum value of a float?

And you would pass in an array of floats, 4 floats per pixel when GL_RGBA is used, correct?

Also, to confirm: GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES is not a parameter for glTexImage2D, but instead is only for verticex, correct?

My iPad 3 reports "GL_OES_texture_float" and "GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear" as being  supported. This means I can indeed use GL_FLOAT as a parameter to glTexImage2D, right? Anyone know if the iPad 2 supports this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range of floating-point values is... [the range of floating-point values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_formats). That's kinda the point of using them. When you fetch from a floating-point texture in a shader, you get the floating-point value stored there. There is no clamping or anything applied.

If you make a half-float texture, then it's values have the range of a 16-bit floating-point value. If you make a single-precision float texture, then it's values have the range of a 32-bit floating-point value.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the first two parts of this question, and I refer you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621095/how-to-use-gl-half-float-oes-typed-textures-in-ios) for the last two parts

> My question is, what is the range of each color component value? 0 to 1.0?

Yes the range is 0.0 to 1.0

[EDIT]
As Nicol Bolas points out, this is not correct, you can use any floating point value, however when that is interpreted as a colour value, it will be clamped to the range (0.0 - 1.0)

> And you would pass in an array of floats, 4 floats per pixel when GL_RGBA is used, correct?

Yes, the floats will be stored in that order also (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha)

Comment: "however when that is interpreted as a colour value, it will be clamped to the range (0.0 - 1.0)" When interpreted by whom? It is "interpreted" by the *shader*, and there, it will be interpreted as a IEEE 754 floating-point value. No clamping of any kind will take place, unless you do it manually.