# Floating point textures in OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS without clamping them to [0, 1]

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios6, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I need gl_FragColor to "paint" floating point values, which also can be negative (x < 0) and > 1.0. I then want to use the color attachement of the FBO this values where rendered to and use it as a texture in another FBO. Now I have read on http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/ (under glTexImage2D) that all values are clamped to a range of [0, 1] and also I didn't find a glClampColor instruction. Is there a possibility to find a workaround here or does somebody have an idea which could help me with my problem? :)

**SOLVED**

It is possible and the values are not clamped to [0, 1] at all, when using floating point textures, but it does only work using GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES as the texture's internal format. Using GL_FLOAT instead results into an incomplete framebuffer object, which is really sad, cause I was building a summed area table (SAT) and got a big precision problem here. So in general it seems like only half precision (2 bytes, 1 sign bit + 5 exponent bits + 10 fraction) floating point numbers are supported on the iPad2.

Working creation of the FBO's color attachement texture

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, NULL);
```

One more thing to mention: Instruments will report an "Invalid enum for argument 'type'" message, but it does work anyway. Also, the simulator will use full precision textures instead the specified half precision (I think cause there is no such data type in C). This is why u propably will get less precision problems on the simulator.

But the most confusing thing is that "GL_OES_texture_float" is supported when printing glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS). However as mentioned before it does not work.

Comment: What is internal type of texture you are using?

Comment: Sorry guys, hope u all had a great holiday. Thank u very very much so far. I will test that this weekend.

Comment: The internal format is GL_RGB. That's why I was worried cause the doc says that only GL_ALPHA, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_RGB and GL_RGBA are allowed and that all of them are clamped to [0,1]

See: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/ under glTexImage2D

Comment: I confirm RayDeeA's solution:  the precision seems to be half float (10 bit mantissa) in MacBookPro (late 2013).  Shame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe this is true for float textures. Check the extension docs:

http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt

It mentions:

"The selected groups are processed as described in section 3.6.2, stopping
    after final expansion to RGBA. If the internal format of the texture is 
    fixed-point, components are clamped to [0,1]. Otherwise, values are not 
    modified."

Comment: I tried to use GL_OES_texture_float as the textures type, but the only result was a log saying that it failed to make a complete framebuffer object aka 8cd6. :(

Comment: It is definitely possible to use float textures on iOS, but you are going to have to show some code if you expect anyone to help.

Comment: You were right. It is possible and the values are not clamped at all, but it does only work using GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES as the internal format. Using GL_FLOAT instead results into an incomplete framebuffer object. So it seems like only half precision floating point numbers are allowed on iPad2. 

One more thing to mention: 
Instruments reports an "Invalid enum for argument 'type'" message, but it does work anyway.

Ah and another weired thing is also that glreadpixels, does only work using GL_FLOAT as the format GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES results in different  floating point numbers.

Thank u very much!

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing about float textures is to support aprox [+inf,-inf] in shaders. You may find more useful information here: [render to floating point texture under iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850569/render-to-floating-point-texture-under-ios)